# Добавить описание под панорамой в окне балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/panorama_in_balloon

вот по этому примеру при открытии балуна отображается панорама.
а можно ли добавить текст с описанием под панорамой?

чтобы было вот так как на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно

```
var BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<p>текст над панорамой</p><div id="panorama" style="width:256px;height:156px"/>'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pwbfj74q/